# Raphael.js: Drawing a circle with an edge border and a fill colour

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

drawing SVGs with numbers is confusing but very, very useful. By modding other people's examples, I have a Raphael.js function that takes 60 seconds to draw a thick green line around a circle with text in the center of it. Here it is in JSFiddle form, with a black background on the container Div to show that there is currently no background colour on the circle:

http://jsfiddle.net/8NZfU/1/

Here's the JS:

```
//60s circular timer
function timer60s() {

var archtype = Raphael("canvas60s", 200, 200);
var set = archtype.set();

function drawCircle() {
  var archtype = Raphael("canvas60s", 200, 200);
  archtype.customAttributes.arc = function (xloc, yloc, value, total, R) {
    var alpha = 360 / total * value,
        a = (90 - alpha) * Math.PI / 180,
        x = xloc + R * Math.cos(a),
        y = yloc - R * Math.sin(a),
        path;
    if (total == value) {
      path = [
          ["M", xloc, yloc - R],
          ["A", R, R, 0, 1, 1, xloc - 0.01, yloc - R]
      ];
    } else {
      path = [
          ["M", xloc, yloc - R],
          ["A", R, R, 0, +(alpha > 180), 1, x, y]
      ];
    }
    return {
       path: path
    };
  };


  var my_arc = archtype.path().attr({
      "stroke": "#339933",
      "stroke-width": 10,
      arc: [100, 100, 0, 100, 50]
  });



  my_arc.animate({
     arc: [100, 100, 100, 100, 50]
  }, 60000);


} //end drawCircle





    drawCircle();

  } // end timer60s

  timer60s();
```

What I want is to create the effect of a white background on the whole circle inside of where the arc is drawn. I also want to add static thin green borders to either side of the arc, so that it appears that the arc is slowly filling in between the lines.

I haven't had any success drawing this background + borders in either CSS or Raphael- can anyone suggest an approach that could work, based on my JSFiddle?

Comment: That was a very well explained and nicely presented question. And the solution looks so neat too. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure, but are you able to draw a second circle?

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/5knjn/

```
archtype.circle(100, 100, 50).attr({
    "fill": "#fff",
    "stroke": "#fff",
    "stroke-width": "10"
});
```

I didn't understand the part:

`I also want to add static thin green borders to either side of the arc, so that it appears that the arc is slowly filling in between the lines.`

So I came up with :) http://jsfiddle.net/5knjn/1/

Also I don't like the way you enter text in the canvas.

You could use [Raphael.text()](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.text)

Included text: http://jsfiddle.net/5knjn/2/

Comment: Thanks for all the examples, this is very useful!